# iOS - TableCell UILabel color while pressed

Tags: ios, uitableview

I can do this to change the color once a cell is selected:

```
cell.myLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

But how can I change it to that color while the cell is being pressed?

Comment: Is 'cell' a plain old UITableViewCell or a custom class? In my own app, as I press down on a cell, the titleLabel shows the highlighted text color and the cell has the selection color as a background. What are you seeing as you hold your finger down on the cell? Are you setting any other attributes of the cell?

Comment: @maddy it's a custom class. I see the highlightedImage on the image view. But the text doesn't change color until I actually let up on the press and it becomes selected.

Comment: I don't see this behavior in my own custom cells. Did you override any of the UITableViewCell methods such as setSelected:animated: or setHighlighted:animated: ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a cell cannot be pressed. In order to get the same functionality just add a *button* (keep it in *hidden state*) into your custom cell.
then simply initialise and make connection.
then

```
if(cell.myButton isSelected YES)
{
     //write code to get details about that particular cell whic is selectd!!
     cell.myLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```